# A possible Property of Euler's totient function: $n$ such that $\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n+1)$ are both powers of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

$n$ is an odd positive integer such that $\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n+1)$ are both powers of two . Here , $\varphi(n)$ denotes Euler's totient function.

> Is it true that $(n+1)$ is either $6$ or a power of $2$?

Please help me to prove or disprove this statement . (I was randomly flipping through some values attained by the $\varphi$ function when I observed this pattern) :)

Comment: If $n$ is a Fermat prime (of the form $2^{2^k}+1$) then certainly both $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(n-1)$ will be powers of $2$. Other than that, after checking up to about $35000$ , I can't find any other $n$.

Comment: The conjecture is true, and moreover there are finitely many possible $n$. I am writing an answer now.

Comment: @ above , can you please provide a link / reference or the answer ?

Comment: @florence: Your statement applies for even $n$ such that $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(n+1)$ are powers of two, but the question is about odd $n$. But the answer still involves Fermat primes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are exactly **seven** odd positive integers $n$ such that

> $\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n+1)$ are both powers of two.

These are:
$$n = 1, 3, 5, 15, 255, 65535, 4294967295.$$
Written out more helpfully:
\begin{align*}
5&\; \\
1&= 2^{2^0} - 1 \\
3&= 2^{2^1} - 1 = 3\\
15 &= 2^{2^2} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5 \\
255 &= 2^{2^3} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \\
65535 &= 2^{2^4} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \\
4294967295 &= 2^{2^5} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537.
\end{align*}
In particular, **your conjecture is true:**
either $n+1 = 6$, or $n+1$ is a power of two. Specifically, $n+1$ is either $6$ or equal to $2^{2^k}$ for $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

You may recognize $3, 5, 17, 257, 65537$ as the known [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number).
The reason there are no larger $n$ is that the next Fermat number,
$4294967297$, is famously composite and equal to $641 \cdot 6700417$.
(Though Fermat conjectured that all Fermat numbers are prime, other than the first five no other Fermat primes are known, and some have conjectured there are no others. See e.g. [this oeis entry](http://oeis.org/A019434).)

---

#### Proof

First, we show that for a positive integer $m$, $\varphi(m)$ is a power of two if and only if $m$ is a power of two times a product of zero or more Fermat primes, i.e. primes of the form $2^{2^a} + 1$. (The same is found in Mathematician 42's answer.) Assume that $\varphi(m)$ is a power of two. If $m$ is divisible by the square of any prime $p$, then $p \mid \varphi(m)$ so $p = 2$. Therefore, $m$ is a power of two times some distinct odd primes $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_i$:
$$
m = 2^x p_1 p_2 \cdots p_i
$$
Thus,
$$
\varphi(m) = 2^{x-1} (p_1 - 1) (p_2 - 1) \cdots (p_i - 1),
$$
and it follows that each $p_i$ must be a power of two plus 1. And the only prime numbers of the form $2^k + 1$ are of the form $2^{2^k} + 1$ (Fermat primes); a quick proof can be found [in this section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers). So $p_i$ is a Fermat prime. Conversely, any $m$ of this form has $\varphi(m)$ being a power of two.

Back to the problem, then, we are looking for all odd positive integers $n$ such that $n, n+1$ are both a power of two times a product of Fermat primes. As $n$ is odd, $n$ must be a product of Fermat primes, and $n+1$ must be a power of two times such a product.
To reduce down to only seven possible $n$, we will exploit the fact that a product of Fermat primes has a very, very structured binary expansion.

Let
$$
n = \prod_{i=1}^l (2^{2^{a_i}} + 1),
$$
where $0 \le a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_l$ and each term of the product is prime.
Expanding out the product, we get that
$$
n = \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,2,3,\ldots, l\}}
2^{\displaystyle \left( \sum_{i \in S} 2^{a_i} \right)}
$$
What this scary formula is saying is that: $n$ is the sum of $2^l$ *distinct* powers of two, and the exponents on those powers of two are all possible sums of $2^{a_1}, 2^{a_2}, \ldots, 2^{a_l}$. Thinking in binary:

- $n$ has $2^l$ digits which are ones;
- $n$ is odd, so the last digit is also a $1$.
- And, importantly, if $l \ge 1$ then $n$ consists of two identical blocks: digits $0$ through $2^{a_l} - 1$ and $2^{a_l}$ through $2^{a_l+1}$ are the same. The block may start with some $0$s. (Within each of the two blocks we then have two more identical blocks, and so on, but there may be zeroes padded on at each step. *Example:* $(2^{2^0} + 1)(2^{2^1}+1)(2^{2^3}+1) = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 257$ is $111100001111$ in binary. The two identical blocks are $00001111$ and $00001111$. Then each block consists of the two identical blocks $11$ and $11$, although four $0$s are padded on in front. Then each of those consists of two identical blocks $1$ and $1$.)

By the same reasoning, $n+1$ must be a power of two times a number that looks exactly the same. We can say that for some $r,m$ and $0 \le b_1 < b_2 < \ldots < b_m$, $n+1$ equals $2^r$ times the product of $2^{2^{b_i}} + 1$, and then:

- $n+1$ has $2^m$ digits which are ones;
- $\frac{n+1}{2^r}$ consists of two identical blocks: digits $0$ through $2^{b_m} - 1$ and $2^{b_m}$ through $2^{b_m + 1}$ are the same. (Within each of the two blocks we then have two more identical blocks, and so on.)

To form $n+1$ from $n$, we add $1$ to the binary expansion, so the number of $1$s decreases by $(c-1)$, where $c$ is the number of $1$s at the end of the binary expansion of $n$. As $n$ has $2^l$ ones, $n+1$ has $2^l - (c-1)$ ones. Since this has to be a power of two, we must either have $c = 1$ or $c \ge 2^{l-1}+1$.
In the former case, we will show that $n$ must equal $5$.
In the latter, that $n$ must equal $2^{2^l} - 1$.

**Case 1: $c = 1$**

Since $c = 1$, $n$ has $01$ at the end of its binary expansion. So $n+1$ has the same binary expansion with $01$ replaced by $10$, and $r = 1$ (number of twos dividing $n+1$).
By looking at the $1$s in $n+1$, we may extract exactly the numbers $b_i$: the $2^i$th 1 from the right, if we start counting from 0, is at position $2^{b_i} + 1$ (where positions start counting from $0$ as well, i.e. the $k$th position is the $2^k$s digit). But it is also at position $2^{a_i}$. It follows that only $a_i = 1$ is possible, and $l = 1, m = 1$, $n = 2^{2^1} + 1 = 5$, $n+1 = 6 = 2 \cdot 3$.

**Case 2: $c \ge 2^{l-1} + 1$**

Here, $n$ must have at least $2^{l-1} + 1$ *consecutive ones* at the right. But $n$ consists of two identical blocks, each containing $2^{l-1}$ ones. So there must not be any zeroes in each block: $n$ must be a string of $2^{l}$ consecutive ones. That is, exactly,
$$
n = 2^{2^l} - 1.
$$
Now, this factors as
$$
n = (2^{2^0} + 1) (2^{2^1} + 1) (2^{2^2} + 1) \cdots (2^{2^{l-1}} + 1).
$$
For $l \le 5$, all of these factors are prime and we have a genuine solution.

But for $l \ge 6$, the factor $(2^{2^{5}} + 1)$ is present, and factors into $641 \cdot 6700417$, which makes $\varphi(n)$ divisible by $640$ and thus not a power of two.

Comment: This answer deserves many upvotes. Brilliant answer, especially the formula for $n$ in terms of power of $2$ is very elegant. Also the OP has done a good job in finding this pattern.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thanks :) Yes, this simple pattern found by the OP turned out to be very cool.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but might be useful when someone smarter than me tries to prove this.

Write $n=\prod_{i}p_i^{n_i}$ and $n+1=\prod_{i}(p_i')^{m_i}$. Then $\phi(n)=\prod_{i} p_i^{n_i-1}(p_i-1)$ being a power of two implies that if $p_i\neq 2$, then $n_i=1$ and $(p_i-1)$ is a power of two. The same holds for $\phi(n+1)$.

Let $I$ be an enumeration of the prime numbers such that the prime number minus one is a power of two, i.e. $0$ corresponds to $2$, $1$ corresponds to $5$, $2$ corresponds to $17$ and so on. Then $$n=2^{n_0}\prod_{i\in I, i\geq 1}p_i^{n_i}$$ where $n_i\in \left\{0,1\right\}$ and $$n+1=2^{m_0}\prod_{i\in I,i\geq 1}p_i^{m_i}$$
where $m_i\in \left\{0,1\right\}$. Here $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime number such that $p_i-1$ is a power of $2$ (and we start counting from zero). From this we get that $$2^{n_0}\prod_{i\in I, i\geq 1}p_i^{n_i}+1=2^{m_0}\prod_{i\in I, i\geq 1}p_i^{m_i}.$$

From this equation, we should be able to find something, however, I do not even know whether the index set $I$ is finite or not, making further manipulations difficult.

Comment: Is it helpful to work in binary ?

Comment: Not sure whether that would help. I'd like to remark that since $n$ is odd, $n_0=0$, further simplifying the equations. I'm curious to see a proof of this fact.

Comment: +1, This answer goes in the right direction. The primes in question (indexed by $I$) are Fermat primes, $2^{2^k} + 1$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$: that is, $3, 5, 17, 257, 65537$, and no others are known, and it is conjectured these are the only ones. However, even without knowing whether $I$ is finite or not once you know that $n$ is a product of these special primes its binary expansion is of a very specific form and you can exploit this to get down to just 7 possible $n$. This is explained in my answer.